# pytest coverage 'if 0:' statement body not listed as a miss

Tags: python, pytest, code-coverage

Test marks the code as covered if the condition is 0 but as uncovered if the condition is a variable with value of zero.

I was trying a simple thing in pytest with coverage and I found this bug (?). I am not sure if I am missing something in how pytest or python works.

Here bellow is my function

```
def dummy_func(a=0):
    
    if a:
        print('this part is not tested !!')
    else:
        print('this part is tested !!')
    
    if 0: # tried None as well  
        print('this part is not tested, but appears like it is !') 
    else:
        print('this part is tested !!')

return 1
```

and this is the report I got

```
---------- coverage: platform linux, python 3.10.6-final-0 -----------
Name                     Stmts   Miss  Cover   Missing
------------------------------------------------------
myproject/flask_api.py       7      1    86%   4
tests/test_hello.py          4      0   100%
------------------------------------------------------
TOTAL                       11      1    91%
```

Should not the line under the if 0 be marked as Miss.
Is that a bug or I am missing something ?

I got that in both version

pytest-cov = "4.0.0" and "3.0.0"
also with coverage

my test code is that

```
from myproject import flask_api

def test_dummy():
    result = flask_api.dummy_func()

    assert result == 1
```

Comment: FYI, no need to put the language in the title when it doesn't fit organically -- a language from the set of applied tags is added to the page description if not present.

Comment: The line under the `if 0` is an unreachable code. So this IMHO a reasonable behavior from `code-coverage`. For the "why this happens", it's either code-cov is smart enough to do so or the python interpreter is smart enough to optimize its compilation to exclude this line thus code-cov doesn't even see it.

Comment: @YevhenKuzmovych how is that a reasonable behavior ? Since it's unreachable code it should be reported as untested, which is not. I do not see anything smart from cov or py aspect, the purpose it to take an error in this line or a miss so you know that you missed it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So the answer to your question is that it's not a bug, it's expected behavior.

From the [`coverage.py` docs](https://coverage.readthedocs.io/en/6.6.0b1/howitworks.html#analysis):

> After your program has been executed and the line numbers recorded,
> coverage.py needs to determine what lines ***could have been executed***.
> Luckily, compiled Python files (.pyc files) have a table of line
> numbers in them. Coverage.py reads this table to get the set of
> executable lines, with a little more source analysis to leave out
> things like docstrings.

and

> The data file is read to get the set of lines that were executed. The
> difference between **the executable lines** and **the executed lines** are **the lines that were not executed**.

and

> The same principle applies for branch measurement, though the process
> for determining possible branches is more involved. Coverage.py uses
> the abstract syntax tree of the Python source file to determine the
> set of possible branches.

That is just how `coverage.py` works. It does not consider unreachable code in its report. It doesn't mark it as missed but it doesn't mark it as tested either.

For instance, here is how the report looks in PyCharm (note the unmarked line 7):

[image]

Some more examples:

[image]

*Interestingly enough, PyCharm can't evaluate `'a' * 0` as "always falsy" but can evaluate `'a'.replace('a', '')` as such, while `coverage.py` does the opposite.*

Comment: Yes after re-thinking your comment, I figure out something like that and I think you are right in a way it is a 'reasonable behavior'. Because unreachable != unexecuted.
Although my objection is that this behavior does not help you to find bugs in your code.

Comment: Yeah, I understand your concern and this is very much an opinion-based question of whether it should be marked as missed or ignored. I might even argue the pro-mark-as-miss argument as marking it as miss might help you find unreachable code. But this is a very specific situation as coverage.py considers unreachable code only for constants or simple mathematical equations. E.x. contents of `if 'a'.replace('a', ''):` will be part of "reachable" code and will be marked as a "miss" (I guess because you technically could mock the `str.replace` in your tests).